# Confusion over seperation of concerns in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've written several MVVM applications over the last year using [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/), but I feel like some part of this design pattern is still escaping me.

Right now, I'm working on an application that interacts with devices. Let's assume it consists of the following components:

- `ShellView / ShellViewModel` - Basic `Conductor<T>` bound to a custom `INavigationService`.
- `SelectView / SelectViewModel` - Displays a list of devices.
- `ControlView / ControlViewModel` - Interacts with a device.

Now, from a UX perspective, I want any errors that occur while connecting to a device to be reported by the `SelectView`. However, from a separation of concerns perspective, the `SelectViewModel` shouldn't contain the device connection code since it's specific to the `ControlViewModel`.

My previous solution was to have the `SelectViewModel` call an initialization function on the `ControlViewModel` instance before navigating to it, but this feels wrong and is no longer possible now that I'm using an `INavigationService`.

I'm sure this comes down to me "just not getting it", but in this example where should I put the device connection code?

### Update

After doing some more research, I think my problems may be caused by a misunderstanding of the model layer in MVVM. I've been putting most of my application logic in my view models, but should I be putting it in separate models instead?

In this case, my `SelectViewModel` could build up an instance of `ControlModel`, handle any errors, and use the `INavigationService` to inject it into a property on the `ControlViewModel`.

Comment: Review the mediator pattern. something like event notifications. I believe micro has an event aggregater for just that purpose.

Comment: Could you have your control viewmodel raise an error event, that is consumed by the select viewmodel, then pass the control viewmodel to the constructor of the select viewmodel?

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern as @Nkosi said. I think it's a good way

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure how the mediator pattern solves my issue. The SelectViewModel is unable to communicate with the ControlViewModel, since the INavigationService ensures they aren't in memory at the same time. I could move the device connection code to the ShellViewModel, but I feel this also violates separation of concerns.

Comment: why not have a class / project / dll that makes all the interaction with the devices all the other viewmodels able to take advantage of it? This is very common for me as I have a database that is used by several softwares with various patterns but using the same business rules so I can use a common dll to various softwares and use in as many viewmodels and / or different software I wish

Comment: "the INavigationService ensures they aren't in memory at the same time" -- it seems as if you have a design requirement that they need to be in memory at the same time. What is INavigationService doing for you that justifies turning trivial problems like this into big issues?

Comment: @CelsoLívero I already have a separate class library of device drivers. However, the driver objects can be initialized with different parameters, and initialization can fail for one reason or another. My problem is the SelectViewModel needs to handle any errors during initialization, but only the ControlViewModel knows how to correctly initialize the device drive object for itself.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Consistency. An INavigationService backed by a Frame is the de facto method of navigation for UWP apps. By creating my own implementation that is backed by a Conductor<T> rather than a Frame, I'm able to use the same navigation style in my WPF apps.

Comment: @NeilThiessen Ah, de facto. Now I understand.